# How do I upload an Arduino STM32 binary from the Mac command line?

Tags: uploading, mac-os, command-line

I've compiled an Arduino program via a Makefile and have the resulting hex file.

From the Mac command line, how do I upload this hex file to my [STM32 Cortex M3](https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32-32-bit-arm-cortex-mcus.html) board?  For an ATMEL processor I would use avrdude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several different tools for uploading binaries to a Cortex M3.  Depending on the board (not chip) configuration, they include (ht: Majenko):

- dfu-util through an FT232 adapter
- stm32flash through serial
- micronucleus through the Micronucleus bootloader
- stlink through an STLink programmer

Many Arduino flavors use a board with some kind of USB or FT232 adapter.  In this case:

the STM32 line of processors include a [DFU](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/6a/17/92/02/58/98/45/0c/CD00264379.pdf/files/CD00264379.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00264379.pdf) ([device firmware update](https://www.digikey.com/en/articles/techzone/2018/jan/update-firmware-field-using-microcontroller-dfu-mode)) bootloader in ROM.

The [dfu-util](http://dfu-util.sourceforge.net/) project supports a Mac version of dfu-util, their command line DFU tool.

Note that this answer is identical for any binaries which run on the processor, be they Arduino sketches or programs developed with other frameworks.